# Concatenate/merge dataframes in R into vector type cells

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I would like to merge two dataframe into one, each cell becoming a vector or a list.
Columns have the same name in both dataframes. Some columns are made of numerical values that I want to keep as numerical values in the merged dataframe. Some columns are made of characters.

For example I would like from these two dataframes:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(
    xx = c(1:5),
    yy = c(2:6),
    zz = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
DF2 <- data.frame(
    xx = c(3:7),
    yy = c(5:9),
    zz = c("a","i","h","g","f"))
```

Which look like this:

DF1

| xx | yy | zz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a |
| 2 | 3 | b |
| 3 | 4 | c |
| 4 | 5 | d |
| 5 | 6 | e |

DF2

| xx | yy | zz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | a |
| 4 | 6 | i |
| 5 | 7 | h |
| 6 | 8 | g |
| 7 | 9 | f |

To get a dataframe looking like this:

| xx | yy | zz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| c(1,3) | c(2,5) | c(a,a) |
| c(2,4) | c(3,6) | c(b,i) |
| c(3,5) | c(4,7) | c(c,h) |
| c(4,6) | c(5,8) | c(d,g) |
| c(5,7) | c(6,9) | c(e,f) |

I have tried with paste() or str_c() but it always transforms my numerical values into char and it does not create a list or a vector like I want.

Do you know of any functions that coule help me do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some tidyverse, you can invert the lists and then build it all back together.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

as_tibble(map2(DF1, DF2, ~ map(transpose(list(.x, .y)), unlist)))
```

This gets you your data frame of vectors.

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  xx        yy        zz       
  <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
2 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
3 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
4 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
5 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
```

Breaking this down...

1. `transpose(list(.x, .y))` will flip a paired list of columns inside-out from a list of two vectors to a list of 5 elements (one for each row, each with two list elements in it).
2. `map(transpose(list(.x, .y)), unlist))` will iterate over each of the 5 lists and unlist them back from a list of 2 to a vector of 2.
3. `map2(DF1, DF2, ~ map(transpose(list(.x, .y)), unlist))` will iterate over each column pair from DF1 and DF2 (e.g., xx, yy, zz) doing steps 1 and 2.
4. `as_tibble(map2(DF1, DF2, ~ map(transpose(list(.x, .y)), unlist)))` converts the list to a tibble (basically a data.frame).

---

Another thing you can do is stack the data and then `nest()` it. You again need a few steps to do it. This would scale better because you could do this with more than 2 data frames.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(rowid_to_column(DF1),
          rowid_to_column(DF2)) %>% 
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  nest(nest_data = -rowid) %>% 
  unnest_wider(nest_data) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-rowid)
```

This also gets you your data frame of vectors.

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  xx        yy        zz       
  <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
2 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
3 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
4 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
5 <int [2]> <int [2]> <chr [2]>
```

Comment: I actually have 3 dataframes in my real data, your second proposition works perfectly.
Is there a purpose for `group_by(rowid)` and `ungroup()`? I found no difference running the code without these lines

Comment: It was to make sure the rows line up when nesting, but I suppose default behavior in `nest()` takes care of it. They probably can be removed, it is just a bit more explicit. Not hurting anything, but good point.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you matrices in a list:

```
res <- setNames(
 lapply( colnames(DF1), function(x) cbind(DF1[[x]], DF2[[x]]) ), 
colnames(DF1) )
```

To convert the result into a data frame you can use this:

```
data.frame( sapply(
 names(res), function(x){ sapply(
  1:nrow(res$xx), function(y){ list(res[[x]][y,1:ncol(res$xx)]) } 
  ) }
 ) )

    xx   yy   zz
1 1, 3 2, 5 a, a
2 2, 4 3, 6 b, i
3 3, 5 4, 7 c, h
4 4, 6 5, 8 d, g
5 5, 7 6, 9 e, f
```

Put together in a function:

EDIT: Added functionality to apply any number of DFs
(against what the question demands, but seemed to be necessary)

```
morph <- function(...){
  abc <- list(...)
  res <- sapply( colnames(abc[[1]]), function(col) list(
            sapply( abc, function(dfr) dfr[[col]] ) ) )

  data.frame( sapply(
    names(res), function(x){ sapply(
      1:nrow(res[[1]]), function(y){ list(res[[x]][y,1:ncol(res[[1]])]) } 
    ) }
  ) )
}

morph(DF1, DF2, DF2)
       xx      yy      zz
1 1, 3, 3 2, 5, 5 a, a, a
2 2, 4, 4 3, 6, 6 b, i, i
3 3, 5, 5 4, 7, 7 c, h, h
4 4, 6, 6 5, 8, 8 d, g, g
5 5, 7, 7 6, 9, 9 e, f, f
```

Comment: I managed to tranform your solution into what I wanted with this function

`L1_2 <- setNames( lapply( colnames(DF1), function(x) cbind(DF1[[x]], DF2[[x]]) ), colnames(DF1) )

DF_reb <- function(Res){
  m <- length(Res)
  n <- nrow(Res$xx)
  DF <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=n,ncol=m))
  colnames(DF) <- c("xx","yy","zz")
  for (i in 1:n){
    Lxx <- list(Res$xx[i,])
    Lyy <- list(Res$yy[i,])
    Lzz <- list(Res$zz[i,])
    DF$xx[i] <- Lxx
    DF$yy[i] <- Lyy
    DF$zz[i] <- Lzz
   }
  return(DF)
  }

DF1_2 <- DF_reb(L1_2)`
Let me know if it works for you or can be improved

Comment: I added a one-liner to convert the result into a data frame output. Which is now the exact result of @ThomasIsCoding, maybe with the upside of using less built-in functions, but that's just a matter of taste i guess :)

Comment: Added functionality for an arbitrary list of DFs, although the question explicitly states two.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. Your response and @Adam's one both answer my question,. As it is the first time I use this website, I don't know if there's a way to accept both and if other people need an answer they'll chose the one they prefer or fits best their problem.

Comment: That’s ok! There is always more than one solution and one has to be accepted. Anyhow, thanks for your reply, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

As your data consists of different types, There is no straight forward answer. However I produced some solution, that might do the trick by creating a nested list. Let me know, if this is what you need:

```
library(BBmisc)
library(dplyr)

colvec <- c("xx2","yy2","zz2")
colnames(DF2) <- colvec

DF <- bind_cols(DF1,DF2)
cols.num <- c("xx","xx2","yy","yy2")
DF[cols.num] <- sapply(DF[cols.num],as.character)
DF <- DF[,c(1,4,2,5,3,6)] 

xx <- convertRowsToList(DF[,1:2])
yy <- convertRowsToList(DF[,3:4])
zz <- convertRowsToList(DF[,5:6])

final_list <- list(xx,yy,zz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following base R option

```
> data.frame(Map(function(x, y) asplit(cbind(x, y), 1), DF1, DF2))
    xx   yy   zz
1 1, 3 2, 5 a, a
2 2, 4 3, 6 b, i
3 3, 5 4, 7 c, h
4 4, 6 5, 8 d, g
5 5, 7 6, 9 e, f
```